# How to receive sms on asp.net using nexmo service

Tags: sms, vonage

I need some guidance on what steps I should follow to receive sms messages using service  from www.nexmo.com.
I am not familiar with asp.net but I am very familiar with C# on windows, so please if you can provide a few steps to get me going then I can pick it up from there.  Right now I have an account at www.godaddy.com, so I am hoping I can write the code to place it there.  I don't really need much details on how to use nexmo service, I mainly need to know what I should do on my web site to receive sms from nexmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incoming SMS's are simply HTTP requests to your 'page'. Nexmo send's the SMS and related data just like a HTML from submits data to a URL using a GET (query string) or POST (form encoded),

So all you have to do is point Nexmo to the URL you want to use, and check the incoming request for the data. Here's the [documentation for incoming messages](http://nexmo.com/documentation/index.html#mo).

Here's a [community authored C# library](https://github.com/siutin/Nexmo-CSharp-lib) that might be be helpful.

(*Disclaimer: I do a bit of developer evangelism for Nexmo.*)

Comment: Awesome, this will definitely get me going; thank you very much.

Comment: I still dont get it. Is there a sample code on how to configure nexmo to handle inbound message and how the callback page should look like ?